# Conditional regexp_replace Oracle / PLSQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying to do a conditional replace within one regexp_replace statement.

For example, if I have the string, `'Dog Cat Donkey'`, I would like to be able to replace `'Dog'` with `'BigDog'`, `'Cat'` with `'SmallCat'` and `'Donkey`' with `'MediumDonkey'` to get the following:

```
'BigDog SmallCat MediumDonkey'
```

I can do it where all are prefixed with the word Big but can't seem to make it replace conditionally.

I currently have this

```
select regexp_replace('Dog Cat Donkey', '(Cat)|(Dog)|(Donkey)', ' Big\1\2\3')
from dual
```

but of course this only returns 'BigDog BigCat BigDonkey'.

I'm aware this isn't the best way of doing this but is it possible?

Comment: You can only conditionally replace in Boost regex. No way with  Oracle regex.

Comment: Can't you use multiple expressions like Bigs `Dog|Wolf|Dingo`, and Smalls like `Cat|Persian`, and Mediums `Donkey|Horse` ? If you can't do a callback, then It can't be done all at once. Of course you can also add boundary's around the alternations, like word `\b(list)\b` and whitespace `(?<!\S)(list)(?!\S)` if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered just doing multiple `replace()`s?

```
select replace(replace(replace(str, 'Dog', 'BigDog'), 'Cat', 'SmallCat'), 'Donkey', 'MediumDonkey')
```

I get that `regexp_replace()` is really powerful.  And it might be able to do this.  But I'm not sure that's a better solution in terms of expressing what you are doing.

Comment: I completely agree! It's to solve an office argument of possibility. :)

Comment: If one word is a substring of another there may be problems with this approach.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew . . . And that would be true of the OP's original regular expression as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, because a regex only processes a string once.

Answer (score 1):

Query -

```
select listagg(final_str,' ') within group (order by sort_str) as output from (
SELECT 
    CASE LST
        WHEN 'Dog' THEN 'BigDog'
        WHEN 'Cat' THEN 'SmallCat'
        WHEN 'Donkey' THEN 'MediumDonkey'
    END AS final_str,
    CASE LST
        WHEN 'Dog' THEN 1
        WHEN 'Cat' THEN 2
        WHEN 'Donkey' THEN 3
    END AS sort_str
from (
SELECT
    trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Dog Cat Donkey', '(\S*)(\s*)', 1, LEVEL)) AS LST
FROM
    DUAL
CONNECT BY
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('Dog Cat Donkey', '(\S*)(\s*)', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    ));
```

Output -

```
BigDog SmallCat MediumDonkey
```

Answer (score 1):

For conditional replacement via REGEX_REPLACE?

Then currently you can do this by repeating it for each different replacement string.

But you could still use the `|` (OR) within the 1 capture group to change more than 1 word for the same replacement string.

And as Gordon Linoff pointed out.
You don't really need a REGEX_REPLACE when a normal REPLACE is sufficient to match a single word.

```sql
select regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
           regexp_replace( str, 
              '(Dog|Snoopy)', 'Big\1')
            ,'(Cat|Feline)', 'Small\1')
           ,'(Donkey|Ass)', 'Medium\1')
from (select 'You Ass, that is not a Dog, but a Cat on a Donkey.' as str from dual);
```

Returns:

```
You MediumAss, that is not a BigDog, but a SmallCat on a MediumDonkey.
```

Do note however that when using the pipe in a regex, that the order matters. 
So if some words start the same then better put them in order of descending length.
**Example:**

```
select 
regexp_replace(str, '(foo|foobar)', '[\1]') as foo_foobar,
regexp_replace(str, '(foobar|foo)', '[\1]') as foobar_foo
from (select 'foo foobar' as str from dual);
```

Returns:

```
FOO_FOOBAR       FOOBAR_FOO
---------------  ---------------
[foo] [foo]bar   [foo] [foobar]
```